# Panda groupby: counting rows satisfying condition on other columns?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pandas-groupby

I would like to do a `groupby` in pandas obtaining as result a dataframe that has as columns the column used to `groupby`, the number of elements for each group and among them, the number of elements in each group, the number of elements that does/does not satisfy a condition based on another column value.

For example being the input like this:

```
type    success
A       True
B       False
A       False
C       True
```

I would like something like:

```
type    total    numOfSuccess numOfFailure
A       2        1             1
B       1        0             1
C       1        1             0
```

In pyspark I did this like

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
df = df.groupBy("type").agg(\
    F.count('*').alias('total'), \
    F.sum(F.when(F.col('success')=="true", 1).otherwise(0)).alias('numOfSuccess'),
    F.sum(F.when(F.col('success')!="true", 1).otherwise(0)).alias('numOfFails'))
```

while in pandas I can only get the `total` and `numOfSuccess` as:

```
df_new = df.groupby(['type'], as_index=False)['success'].agg({'total':'count', 'numOfSuccess':'sum'})
```

or only the total as:

```
df = df.groupby(['type']).size().reset_index(name='NumOfReqs')
```

but I cannot get the third column `numOfFailures` and plus if there is an alternative rather than summing the boolean values, it would be better since in can be extended to other cases as well easier in my opinion.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) for count all data, then for count per catogories need pivoting - with `GroupBy.size` and [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html), [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.crosstab.html) or [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html):

```
df1 = df.groupby('type').size().reset_index(name='count')
df2 = (df.groupby(['type', 'success']).size().unstack(fill_value=0)
        .rename(columns={True:'numOfSuccess', False:'numOfFails'}))
```

Alternative for `df2`:

```
df2 = pd.crosstab(df['type'], df['success'])
        .rename(columns={True:'numOfSuccess', False:'numOfFails'}))
```

Or:

```
df2 = (df.pivot_table(index='type', columns='success', fill_value=0, aggfunc='size')
        .rename(columns={True:'numOfSuccess', False:'numOfFails'}))
```

---

```
df_new = df1.join(df2, on='type')
print (df_new)
  type  count  numOfFails  numOfSuccess
0    A      2           1             1
1    B      1           1             0
2    C      1           0             1
```

Another solution is use parameter `margins` in [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.crosstab.html) and remove last row by indexing with [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
df = (pd.crosstab(df['type'], df['success'], margins=True)
        .rename(columns={True:'numOfSuccess', False:'numOfFails', 'All':'count'})
        .iloc[:-1]
        .reset_index()
        .rename_axis(None, axis=1))

print (df)
  type  numOfFails  numOfSuccess  count
0    A           1             1      2
1    B           1             0      1
2    C           0             1      1
```

EDIT: If possible `True` or `False` not exist, add [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) for add missing column:

```
print (df)
  type  success
0    A     True
1    B     True
2    A     True
3    C     True

df1 = df.groupby('type').size().reset_index(name='count')
df2 = (df.groupby(['type', 'success']).size().unstack(fill_value=0)
         .reindex(columns=[True, False], fill_value=0)
         .rename(columns={True:'numOfSuccess', False:'numOfFails'}))


df_new = df1.join(df2, on='type')
print (df_new)
  type  count  numOfSuccess  numOfFails
0    A      2             2           0
1    B      1             1           0
2    C      1             1           0
```

Comment: Great solution.! +1

Comment: @MayankPorwal - Thank you!

Comment: Hi thanks for the solutions...There is a minor problem though: if success column is all true, `numOfFails` column will not exist. Is there a simple solution to this?

Comment: @FrancescoBoi - sure, give me a sec

Comment: Thanks a lot. Great answer and you ve been very heplful and kind.